# What is the use of matching constraints in inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

From the following link, 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ia/index.html

> a single variable may serve as both the input and the output operand.

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int num = 1;
    asm volatile ("incl %0"
            :"=a"(num)
            :"0"(num));
    printf("num:%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code increments the value of num.

What is the use of matching constraints, if i don't use matching constraints, the code does not work as expected.

```
asm volatile ("incl %0"
                :"=a"(num));
```

Comment: Based on the title, I thought the question was going to be "why do matching constraints exist when you can just use `"+r"(var)` for a read/write operand, instead of the more complicated matching-constraint syntax?".  That would have been interesting.  IDK why you'd have any expectation that an output-only operand would be useful with `inc`.

Comment: In addition to what Michael says in his answer, there's also the idea of c = a + b aka `asm ("add %2,%0" :"=a"(numC) :"0"(numA), "r" (numB));`.  This puts numA in eax on input, but specifies that eax will be numC on output.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that's the question, why and when should we use matching constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why and when should we use matching constraints

That's not the question you asked; you asked why you need an input at all, which should be fairly obvious when you know what the syntax actually means.  (That `"=r"(var)` is a pure output, independent of any previous value the C variable had, like `var = 123;` would be).  So `"=r"` with an `inc` instruction is like `var = stale_garbage + 1;`

---

But anyway, as I commented, the interesting question is "**why do matching constraints exist when you can just use `"+r"(var)` for a read/write operand, instead of the more complicated matching-constraint syntax?**"

**They're rarely useful; usually you can use the same variable for input and output especially if you have your asm inside a C wrapper function**.  But if you don't want to use the same C var for input and output, but still need them to pick the same register or memory, then you want a matching constraint.  One use-case might be wrapping a system call is one use-case; you might want to use a different C variable for the call number vs. the return value.  (Except you could just use `"=a"` and `"a"` instead of a matching constraint; the compiler doesn't have a choice.)  Or maybe an output var of a narrower or different type than the input var could be another use-case.

IIRC, x87 is another use-case; I seem to recall `"+t"` not working.

I think that `"+r"` RMW constraints are internally implemented as an output with a "hidden" matching constraint.  But while `%1` normally errors in an asm template that only has one operand, if that operand is an in/out `"+something"` then GCC doesn't reject `%1` as being too high an operand number.  And if you look at the asm to see which register or memory it actually chose for that out-of-bounds operand number, it does match the in/out operand.

So `"+r"` is basically syntactic sugar for matching constraints.  I'm not sure if it was new at some point, and before GCC version x.y you had to use matching constraints?  It's not rare to see tutorial examples that use matching constraints with the same var for both input and output that would simpler to read with `"+"` RMW constraints.

---

Basics:

With constraints like `"a"` and `"=a"` you don't *need* a matching constraint; the compiler only has 1 choice anyway.  Where it's useful is `"=r"` where the compiler could pick any register, and you need it to pick the *same* register for an input operand.

If you just used `"=r"` and a separate `"r"` input, you'd be telling the compiler that it can use this as a copy-and-whatever operation, leaving the original input unmodified and producing the output in a new register.  Or overwriting the input if it wants to.  That would be appropriate for `lea 1(%[srcreg]), %[dstreg]` but not `inc %0`.  The latter would assume that %0 and %1 are the same register, therefore you need to do something to make sure that's true!

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
asm volatile ("incl %0"
                :"=a"(num));
```

Doesn't work because in order to increase the value in a register (by 1 in this case) an original value needs to be read from the register; 1 added to it; and the value written back to the register. `=a` only says that the output of the register EAX will be moved to `num` when finished but the compiler won't load the register EAX with the original value of `num`. The code above will just add 1 to whatever happens to be in EAX (could be anything) and puts that in `num` when the inline assembly is finished.

```
asm volatile ("incl %0"
        :"=a"(num)
        :"0"(num));
```

On the other hand this says that `num` is both used as an input (so the value of `num` is moved to EAX) and that it also outputs a value in EAX so the compiler will move the value in EAX to `num` when the inline assembly is finished.

It could have been rewritten to use an  input/output constraint as well (this does the same thing):

```
asm volatile ("incl %0"
        :"+a"(num));
```

There is no need for `volatile` here either since all of the side effects are captured in the constraints. Adding `volatile` unnecessarily can lead to less efficient code generation but the code will still work. I would have written it this way:

```
asm ("incl %0"
     :"+a"(num));
```

Comment: Is not = in constraint compulsory for output operand?

Comment: @md.jamal : An output constraint must be some form of `output`. `=` is output only and `+` is output and input. Both output only `=` and input and output `+` constraints are specified in the output section. Only input only constraints are in the input section.