# cmpxchgl opcode: when did EAX get loaded in this code example?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I understand that the `cmpxchgl` opcode compares an operand with the accumulator. In this `asm` statement the accumulator doesn't seem to be loaded before the `lock`. How did the accumulator get loaded with
`_old` to be used as the expected value? I.e. there does not seem
to be a (pseudo-code) `mov eax, _old`

I see the contraint `"0" (_old)`indicates `_old` will be an input but why does 0 mean that it gets loaded into `EAX`?

```
/* TODO: You should use modern GCC atomic instruction builtins instead of this. */
#include <stdint.h>
#define cmpxchg( ptr, _old, _new ) { \
  volatile uint32_t *__ptr = (volatile uint32_t *)(ptr);   \
  uint32_t __ret;                                     \
  asm volatile( "lock; cmpxchgl %2,%1"           \
    : "=a" (__ret), "+m" (*__ptr)                \
    : "r" (_new), "0" (_old)                     \
    : "memory");                 \
  );                                             \
  __ret;                                         \
}
```

When the file was compiled, there was indeed an instruction

```
39:       8b 45 e4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c]
```

to setup the accumulator but I would like to know where did
this setup statement come from.

Comment: The `0` constraint means that the operand occupies the same location as operand `0`, i.e. `eax`.

Comment: Note quite a duplicate of [What is the use of matching constraints in inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59655840) - that mostly assumes readers know that `"0"` means "pick the same register as the `%0` operand for this input.